# How to make a generic Jscript function to work with dynamic form

Tags: javascript, function, generics, field

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(){
     s1 = document.ins_form.servizio.value;
     valori = s1.split("|");
     document.ins_form.codice.value = valori[0];
     document.ins_form.costouno.value = valori[1];
}
</script>


<form action="" method="post" name="ins_form" id="ins_form">
<select name="servizio" id="servizio" onchange="populate()">
    <option value="">Choose..</option>
    <option value="100|10">choice one</option>
    <option value="302|32">choice two</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" name="codice" id="codice" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" name="costouno" id="costouno" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```

This is referring to specific input fields (servizio,codice,costouno) that will be populated by user's choices, with different values, and it works nicely.

I'm not a magician with JScript so I can't find a solution to transform this function in a generic one, to be able and use it on other fields dynamically  generated and that would be like: servizio1,codice1,costouno1 and servizio2,codice2,costouno2 and servizio3 ecc...

Hope it's kinda clear, thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question is "kinda clear", but not clear enough to be answered. Where should the function get the information which value to fill into which field? Also, if all the values are in `document.ins_form.servizio.value` then that means the server fills them in. Why doesn't the server fill them into the correct spots right from the start?

Comment: I've added the form itself so maybe is more clear, the point is: I want to add more rows dynamically to that form and that the function works on the new rows too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the form elements themselves to the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(field1, field2, fromDelimitedString){
   valori = fromDelimitedString.split("|");
   field1.value = valori[0];
   field2.value = valori[1];
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post" name="ins_form" id="ins_form">
<select name="servizio" id="servizio" onchange="populate(document.getElementById('codice'),
document.getElementById('costuono'), document.getElementById('servizio').value)">
    <option value="">Choose..</option>
    <option value="100|10">choice one</option>
    <option value="302|32">choice two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="codice" id="codice" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" name="costouno" id="costouno" readonly="readonly" />
</form>
```